# How to monitor the invocation of methods in abstract class using java agent and ASM?

Tags: java, jvm, instrumentation, java-bytecode-asm, javaagents

What I want to do is to monitor the invocation of JUnit 4 test methods. The reason I must do this by myself is: I need to record the executed classes during the execution of each test method. So I need to insert some instructions to the test method so that I know when the test start/end and those recorded classes are executed by which test entity. So I need to filter the test methods on my own.

Actually, **the reason why I am doing this is not relevant to the question**, as I did not mention "JUnit", "test" in the title. The problem can still be a problem in other similar cases.

The case I have is like this:

```java
public abstract class BaseTest {
    @Test
    public void t8() {
        assert new C().m() == 1;
    }
}
```

```java
public class TestC  extends BaseTest{
    // empty
}
```

I have also modified Surefire's member `argLine` so that my agent will be attached (premain mode) when Surefire launch a new JVM process to execute tests.

In my agent class:

```java
    public static void premain(String args, Instrumentation inst){
        isPreMain = true;
        agentArgs = args;
        log("args: " + args);
        parseArgs(args);
        inst.addTransformer(new TestTransformer(), true);
    }
```

My transformer class:

```java
public class TestTransformer implements ClassFileTransformer {
    public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className,
                            Class<?> classBeingRedefined, ProtectionDomain protectionDomain,
                            byte[] classfileBuffer) throws IllegalClassFormatException {

        log("TestTransformer: transform: " + className);
        ...
        ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(classfileBuffer);
        ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(cr, ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS);
        RecordClassAdapter mca = new RecordClassAdapter(cw, className);
        cr.accept(mca, 0);
        return cw.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

In my ClassVisitor adapter class:

```
class RecordClassAdapter extends ClassVisitor {
    ...
    @Override
    public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String desc, String signature, String[] exceptions) {
        MethodVisitor mv = cv.visitMethod(access, name, desc, signature, exceptions);
        mv = new RecordMethodAdapter (...);
        return mv;
    }
}
```

In my MethodVisitor adapter class:

```java
class RecordMethodAdapter extends MethodVisitor {
    public void visitCode() {
        mv.visitCode();
        if (isTestMethod){
            mv.visitLdcInsn(methodName);
            mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESTATIC, MyClass, "entityStarted",
                    "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", false);
        }
    }
}
```

Sadly, I found that the abstract class will not get into the `transform` method, thus I can not instrument the `t8` method. `TestC` should be executed as a test class, but I can never monitor the invocation of `TestC.t8`.

Comment: How do you register / invoke the transformation? (amend the question with the relevant code, please)

Comment: Why? JUnit 4 does already provide everything needed to monitor the invocations of test methods. In fact, there’s more than one builtin feature you can use to implement such monitoring.

Comment: And even if JUnit did not have such options, why would you develop a custom agent for that instead of using AspectJ? Or if AspectJ is too easy for you and you want to code more, maybe ByteBuddy? ASM is about as low level as it gets for such a simple high level task. Is this just a playground project for learning purposes?

Comment: @apangin I am sorry that I forgot to show those codes. Now I have edited the question. I just used the `addTransformer` method to register. However, I can not find `BaseTest ` in the log, which means it did not get into the `transform` method.

Comment: @kriegaex Actually it is for a serious tool. I use ASM because what I want to do is more than monitoring test execution. Actually I need to record the executed classes during the execution of each test method, so I just use ASM to monitor the start/end of test entities incidentally.

Comment: @Holger Could you please provide more details? Actually I need to record the executed classes during the execution of each test method, so I just use ASM to monitor the start/end of test entities incidentally.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are not using a debugger to put a break point on the base method/inside the method, this is exactly the reason they were written?

Comment: @Chi-YoungJeffreyLii My project is a maven plugin, which is executed when running the goal `test` in Lifecycle. I tried to set a breakpoint, it seems didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

There are several opportunities to inject logging into the test via the JUnit API. There is no need for instrumentation.

For a very simple setup:

```
public class BaseTest {
    @Test
    public void t8() {
        System.out.println("Running  test "+getClass().getName()+".t8() [BaseTest.t8()]");
    }
  
    @Test
    public void anotherMethod() {
        System.out.println("Running  test "
            +getClass().getName()+".anotherMethod() [BaseTest.anotherMethod()]");
    }
}

public class TestC extends BaseTest {
    @Rule
    public TestName name = new TestName();
  
    @Before
    public void logStart() throws Exception {
       System.out.println("Starting test "+getClass().getName()+'.'+name.getMethodName());
    }
  
    @After
    public void logEnd() throws Exception {
       System.out.println("Finished test "+getClass().getName()+'.'+name.getMethodName());
    }
}
```

which will print

```
Starting test class TestC.t8
Running  test TestC.t8() [BaseTest.t8()]
Finished test class TestC.t8
Starting test class TestC.anotherMethod
Running  test TestC.anotherMethod() [BaseTest.anotherMethod()]
Finished test class TestC.anotherMethod
```

You can also implement your own rule. E.g. ad-hoc:

```
public class TestB extends BaseTest {
    @Rule
    public TestRule notify = TestB::decorateTest;
  
    static Statement decorateTest(Statement st, Description d) {
        return new Statement() {
            @Override public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
              System.out.println("Starting test "+d.getClassName()+"."+d.getMethodName());
              st.evaluate();
              System.out.println("Finished test "+d.getClassName()+"."+d.getMethodName());
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Or as a reusable rule that can be inserted via a single-liner into a test class

```
public class LoggingRule implements TestRule {
    public static final LoggingRule INSTANCE = new LoggingRule();
  
    private LoggingRule() {}
  
    @Override
    public Statement apply(Statement base, Description description) {
        Logger log = Logger.getLogger(description.getClassName());
        log.setLevel(Level.FINEST);
        Logger.getLogger("").getHandlers()[0].setLevel(Level.FINEST);
        String clName = description.getClassName(), mName = description.getMethodName();
        return new Statement() {
            @Override
            public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
                log.entering(clName, mName);
                String result = "SUCCESS";
                try {
                    base.evaluate();
                }
                catch(Throwable t) {
                    result = "FAIL";
                    log.throwing(clName, mName, t);
                }
                finally {
                    log.exiting(clName, mName, result);
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

used as simple as

```
public class TestB extends BaseTest {
    @Rule
    public LoggingRule log = LoggingRule.INSTANCE;
}
```

---

A different approach is implementing a custom test runner. This allows to apply a behavior to an entire test suite, as test suites are implemented via runners as well.

```
public class LoggingSuiteRunner extends Suite {
    public LoggingSuiteRunner(Class<?> klass, RunnerBuilder builder)
                                                            throws InitializationError {
        super(klass, builder);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(RunNotifier notifier) {
        notifier.addListener(LOG_LISTENER);
        try {
            super.run(notifier);
        } finally {
            notifier.removeListener(LOG_LISTENER);
        }
    }

    static final RunListener LOG_LISTENER = new RunListener() {
        public void testStarted(Description d) {
            System.out.println("Starting test "+d.getClassName()+"."+d.getMethodName());
        }
        public void testFinished(Description d) {
            System.out.println("Finished test "+d.getClassName()+"."+d.getMethodName());
        }
        public void testFailure(Failure f) {
            Description d = f.getDescription();
            System.out.println("Failed test "+d.getClassName()+"."+d.getMethodName()
                              +": "+f.getMessage());
        };
    };
}
```

This may get applied to an entire test suite, i.e. still inheriting test methods from `BaseTest`, you may use

```
@RunWith(LoggingSuiteRunner.class)
@SuiteClasses({ TestB.class, TestC.class })
public class TestA {}

public class TestB extends BaseTest {}

public class TestC extends BaseTest {}
```

which will print

```
Starting test TestB.t8
Running  test TestB.t8() [BaseTest.t8()]
Finished test TestB.t8
Starting test TestB.anotherMethod
Running  test TestB.anotherMethod() [BaseTest.anotherMethod()]
Finished test TestB.anotherMethod
Starting test TestC.t8
Running  test TestC.t8() [BaseTest.t8()]
Finished test TestC.t8
Starting test TestC.anotherMethod
Running  test TestC.anotherMethod() [BaseTest.anotherMethod()]
Finished test TestC.anotherMethod
```

---

These are only pointers, to suggest studying the API which allows even more. Another point to consider, is that depending on the method you’re using for launching the tests (you mentioned a maven plugin), there might be support for adding a global `RunListener` right there, without the need to alter the test classes.

Comment: did you forgot to include `TestName` class?

Comment: @Eugene no, it’s [`org.junit.rules.TestName`](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/?org/junit/rules/TestName.html)

Comment: @Holger Thanks for your detailed answer! I also want to know that in my case, why the abstract classes can not get into the `transform` method, and is there any way to instrument the method in abstract classes? Maybe I should open a new question for this, but I think maybe you know something about this since you have helped me more than one times : )

Comment: As far as I can see, you are installing a load-time transformer in `premain`, so we should be able to preclude the possibility that the class has been already loaded. There should be a name test in `transform`, to return `null` for classes you’re not interested in, to avoid circular dependencies when classes needed by your agent are loaded. If the unit test actually runs, we also can preclude that the class never gets loaded. I suppose, you did already check that the agent has been installed at all? Then, there is no recognizable reason. Some information must be missing…